# reverse a linked list in groups

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I am now working on reversing a linked list in groups, but encountering some issues.

The question is:

> Given a LinkedList with ‘n’ nodes, reverse it based on its size in the following way:
>
> If ‘n’ is even, reverse the list in a group of n/2 nodes. If n is odd,
> keep the middle node as it is, reverse the first ‘n/2’ nodes and
> reverse the last ‘n/2’ nodes.

My approach is:

```
def lenLinkedlist(head):
    count = 0
    current = head
    while current:
        current = current.next
        count += 1
    return count

def reverseInGroupPart(head, n):
    count = 0
    previous, current, next = None, head, None
    while current and count < n//2:
        next = current.next
        current.next = previous
        previous = current
        current = next
        count += 1
    # even
    if n%2 == 0:
        # current at middle right now
        # head supports to be middle now
        head.next = reverseInGroupPart(current, n)
    # odd
    else:
        # current at middle now
        head.next = current
        current.next = reverseInGroupPart(current.next, n)
    return previous

def reverseGroups(head):
    n = lenLinkedlist(head)
    if n%2 == 0:
        return reverseInGroupPart(head, n)
    else:
        return reverseInGroupPart(head, n)

class Node:
    def __init__(self, _value, _next = None):
        self.value = _value
        self.next = _next
    def print_list(self):
        temp = self
        while temp:
            print(temp.value, end = ' ')
            temp = temp.next
        print()

def main():
    head = Node(1)
    head.next = Node(2)
    head.next.next = Node(3)
    head.next.next.next = Node(4)
    head.next.next.next.next = Node(5)
    head.next.next.next.next.next = Node(6)

    print('original linked list is: ', end = '')
    head.print_list()
    result = reverseGroups(head)
    print('reverse of linked list is ', end = '')
    result.print_list()

main()
```

With errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 58, in main
    result = reverseGroups(head)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 33, in reverseGroups
    return reverseInGroupPart(head, n)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 22, in reverseInGroupPart
    head.next = reverseInGroupPart(current, n)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 22, in reverseInGroupPart
    head.next = reverseInGroupPart(current, n)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 22, in reverseInGroupPart
    head.next = reverseInGroupPart(current, n)
  [Previous line repeated 993 more times]
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/tester/main.py", line 19, in reverseInGroupPart
    if n%2 == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
original linked list is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to use the recursion method to solve the question, but not sure what caused the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `reverseGroups()` function doesn't make much sense as it has an `if` that does the same thing in both branches.

I'm going to take a different approach.  First, I'm going to change your *functions* to instead be *methods* of `Node`.  Next, I'm going to make most of those methods recursive, just for practice. Finally, I'm going to make the reversing of segments of the linked list recursive, but not the higher level logic of rearranging portions of the linked list as that doesn't seem like a recursive problem:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, _next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = _next

    def printLinkedlist(self):
        print(self.value, end=' ')

        if self.next:
            self.next.printLinkedlist()
        else:
            print()

    def lengthLinkedlist(self):
        count = 1

        if self.next:
            count += self.next.lengthLinkedlist()

        return count

    def reverseLinkedList(self, length):
        head, rest = self, self.next

        if length > 1:
            if rest:
                head, rest = rest.reverseLinkedList(length - 1)

                self.next.next = self
                self.next = None

        return head, rest

    def reverseGroups(self):
        head = self
        length = self.lengthLinkedlist()

        if length > 3:
            tail = self
            head, rest = self.reverseLinkedList(length//2)  # left

            if length % 2 == 1:  # odd, skip over middle
                tail.next = rest
                tail = tail.next
                rest = tail.next

            tail.next, _ = rest.reverseLinkedList(length//2)  # right

        return head

if __name__ == '__main__':

    head = Node(1)
    head.next = Node(2)
    head.next.next = Node(3)
    head.next.next.next = Node(4)
    head.next.next.next.next = Node(5)
    head.next.next.next.next.next = Node(6)
    head.next.next.next.next.next.next = Node(7)

    print('original linked list is: ', end='')
    head.printLinkedlist()

    head = head.reverseGroups()

    print('reverse of linked list is ', end='')
    head.printLinkedlist()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
original linked list is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
reverse of linked list is 3 2 1 4 7 6 5 
>
```

And if we comment out the last link:

```
# head.next.next.next.next.next.next = Node(7)
```

Then our output is:

```
> python3 test.py
original linked list is: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
reverse of linked list is 3 2 1 6 5 4 
>
```

For me, this problem turned out to be one of careful bookkeepping.  I also had to first implement `reverseLinkedList()` iteratively, get `reverseGroups()` working, and then go back and reimplement `reverseLinkedList()` recursively.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this problem in small steps. For starters, the class structure could use a bit of an overhaul to make it easier to work with. I'd create a `LinkedList` class and take advantage of the dunder methods like `__repr__`, `__len__` and `__iter__` to make the code cleaner and more Pythonic. Use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

```
from functools import reduce

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next_=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, els):
        self.head = None

        for e in reversed(els):
            self.head = Node(e, self.head)

    def __iter__(self):
        curr = self.head

        while curr:
            yield curr
            curr = curr.next

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        try:
            return list(zip(self, range(i + 1)))[-1][0]
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError(i)

    def __len__(self): # possibly better to cache instead of compute on the fly
        return reduce(lambda a, _: a + 1, self, 0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[" + "->".join([str(x) for x in self]) + "]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for length in range(8):
        ll = LinkedList(list(range(length)))
        print("original:", ll)
```

Before diving into the algorithm, I should note that linked lists are a poor fit for recursion (unless the language is [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimized) because each recursive step only reduces the problem space by 1 node. This incurs a lot of call overhead, risks blowing the stack if the list has more than a measly ~1000 elements and generally doesn't offer much elegance/readability payoff to offset these downsides.

On the other hand, trees are a better fit for recursion because the call stack pops frequently during a traversal of a well-balanced tree, keeping the depth to a logarithmic rather than a linear scale. The same is true for sorting lists with quicksort or mergesort or performing binary searches.

Linked list algorithms also tend to require many references to previous and next nodes, along with bookkeeping nodes for dummy heads and tails, state that isn't easy to access in a discrete stack frame. Iteratively, you can access all of the state you need directly from the loop block without parameters.

That said, here's a simple iterative reversal routine I'll use as the basis for writing the rest of the code:

```
class LinkedList:
    # ...
    def reverse(self):
        prev = None
        curr = self.head

        while curr:
            nxt = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = nxt
    
        self.head = prev
```

This needs to be made more general: if I can refactor this algorithm to reverse a subset of the list between a node and a sublist length, the problem is pretty much solved because we can apply this algorithm to the first and second halves of the list separately.

The first step towards that is to avoid hardcoding `self.head` and pass it in as a parameter, returning the new head for the reversed sublist. This is still in-place (I assume that to be a requirement):

```
class LinkedList:
    # ...
    def _reverse_from(self, curr):
        prev = None

        while curr:
            nxt = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = nxt
    
        return prev

    def reverse(self):
        self.head = self.reverse_from(self.head)
```

Next, we can add an index counter to enable reversal of a subset of the linked list starting from a node.

To make this work, the new tail node (old front node of the sublist) needs to be linked to the back of the list left after the reversed subsection or we'll wind up with the old head/new tail node pointing to `None` and chopping off the tail.

```
class LinkedList:
    # ...
    def _reverse_from(self, start, length=-1):
        curr = start
        prev = None
        
        while curr and length != 0:
            nxt = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = nxt
            length -= 1

        if start:
            # link the new tail (old head) with the back of the list
            start.next = curr

        return prev
```

Finally, add the client-facing function to reverse each half separately:

```
class LinkedList:
    # ...
    def reverse_halves(self):
        length = len(self)
    
        if length < 4:
            return
    
        mid_idx = length // 2 
        self.head = self._reverse_from(self.head, mid_idx)
    
        if length % 2 == 0:
            mid_idx -= 1
    
        mid = self[mid_idx]
        mid.next = self._reverse_from(mid.next)
```

Putting it all together with sample runs, we get:

```
from functools import reduce

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next_=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, els):
        self.head = None

        for e in reversed(els):
            self.head = Node(e, self.head)

    def _reverse_from(self, start, length=-1):
        curr = start
        prev = None
        
        while curr and length != 0:
            nxt = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = nxt
            length -= 1
   
        if start:
            start.next = curr

        return prev

    def reverse(self):
        self.head = self._reverse_from(self.head)

    def reverse_halves(self):
        length = len(self)

        if length < 4:
            return

        mid_idx = length // 2 
        self.head = self._reverse_from(self.head, mid_idx)

        if length % 2 == 0:
            mid_idx -= 1

        mid = self[mid_idx]
        mid.next = self._reverse_from(mid.next)

    def __iter__(self):
        curr = self.head

        while curr:
            yield curr
            curr = curr.next

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        try:
            return list(zip(self, range(i + 1)))[-1][0]
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError(i)

    def __len__(self):
        return reduce(lambda a, _: a + 1, self, 0)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[" + "->".join([str(x) for x in self]) + "]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for length in range(8):
        ll = LinkedList(list(range(length)))
        print("original:", ll)
        ll.reverse_halves()
        print("reversed:", ll, "\n")
```

Output:

```
original: []
reversed: []

original: [0]
reversed: [0]

original: [0->1]
reversed: [0->1]

original: [0->1->2]
reversed: [0->1->2]

original: [0->1->2->3]
reversed: [1->0->3->2]

original: [0->1->2->3->4]
reversed: [1->0->2->4->3]

original: [0->1->2->3->4->5]
reversed: [2->1->0->5->4->3]

original: [0->1->2->3->4->5->6]
reversed: [2->1->0->3->6->5->4]
```